# How do I add certain columns from one datatable into another?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datatable

I have datatables dt1 with productID, productName and productPrice columns, and dt2 with orderID, productID, productName, productPrice and totalPrice. How do i get dt1 info into dt2 while just entering productID?

Comment: Please give us more details(some code etc.). What do you want to do? Display this data?

Comment: I want to store those 3 columns' value from dt1 into dt2 with just entering ProductID in the textbox. then display the results in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, how I read it you kind of want a JOIN function in c# datatable. Did this a long time ago so there are better ways i think...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Give a Table that contains the foreignkeys it returns a Table with a Description instead of the Key
    /// The ID in the source has to be Column[0]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="foreignkeys">Foreignkey in you Table</param>
    /// <param name="source">The Table the foreignkey refers to</param>
    /// <param name="_foreigncolumn">Header of Foreignkeycolumn</param>
    /// <param name="_sourcecolumn">Header description column in source Table</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DataTable getDatabyForeignKey(DataTable foreignkeys, DataTable source, string _foreigncolumn, string _sourcecolumn)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable displayname = new DataTable();
            displayname.Columns.Add("ID");
            //Maybe change that to a parameter as well (amount + header)
            displayname.Columns.Add("Description");

            for (int i = 0; i < foreignkeys.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < source.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    string s = source.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    string ss = foreignkeys.Rows[i][_foreigncolumn].ToString();
                    if (source.Rows[j][0].ToString() == foreignkeys.Rows[i][_foreigncolumn].ToString())
                    {
                        foreignkeys.Rows[i][_foreigncolumn] = source.Rows[j][_sourcecolumn];
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);               
        }

        return foreignkeys;
    }
```